# Cannot access shared folder between two Windows8 computers

Tags: windows-8, shared-folders

How do I share a folder on one Windows8 computer and access it from another Windows8 computer?

I do not want to use HomeGroups. I set them up initially, but I'm much more content with mapped network drives which make sense to me. Homegroups do not.

I have been at this for three hours and am ready to put a computer monitor through the window, but this is what I have tried so far.

Two computers. server@mysite.com and pc@mysite.com which are both Windows8 live accounts or whatever.

1. On server both users have been added. Currently logged in as server@mysite.com.
2. Shared folder "Photos'. I see the shared folder from PC, but access is denied
3. Ran fsmgmt.msc
4. Added full permissions for "Everyone" and for "pc@mysite.com". Access is denied.
5. Tried adding every user under the sun. Access is denied.

Argh.

Answer (score 2):

Well I finally sorted something out by looking at one folder I could access for some unknown reason, a Users folder which was autoshared somehow.

1. Run fsmgmt.msc
2. Find your folder and right click | properties
3. Security tab | Add
4. Under search area enter [server]\users where server is the name of your computer
5. Grant permissions as appropriate after adding

No more access denied error. Very strange considering that I could see pc@mysite.com was a user with full control, yet still couldn't access. Why is this so complicated again?

Comment: "Security Tab > Add"... Do not exist..... Being so complex and you added more mistery on that step.... Neither the Server appeared under "Locations"...

Comment: I put: Security>Add> [MyComputer]\HomeUsers and granted permissions. The name was not the "server" but just the name of the computer where the permission change is made. The only computer listed under the "Locations", btw....

Answer (score 0):

Goto security tab under folder properties and add everyone read/write permission.check your firewall setting. Try sharing after disabling firewall. I know this is a security flaw, but you can check this way and can conclude where the problem exist.